# Build where clause from arrays of strings using contains keyword in SQl Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a string like:

```
"bottle 750 green"
```

The string has a variable number of words each time. I need , based on this string to create:

```
CONTAINS(descr_en,'"*bottle*" and "*750*" and "*green*"')
```

I will then attach this to a where clause on an sql statement in order to get the desired results.

How can i create the resulting contains clause?

I have tried this:

```
var str = "mara 750 bottle";
    string[] strarr = str.Split(' ');
    var result = "";
    foreach (var s in strarr)
    {
        result += "\"*" + s + "*\"" + " AND ";
    }
```

This gives me : `"*mara*" AND "*750*" AND "*bottle*" AND` which is almost what i need.

The only thing i need from the above is to get rid of the training " AND "...

I prefer a clean solution based on LINQ if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.Join(" AND ", "mara 750 bottle".Split(' ').Select (s => string.Format("\"*{0}*\"", s)))
```

gives `"*mara*" AND "*750*" AND "*bottle*"`

Answer (score 0):

/*Why not just build your CONTAINS clause based on:

```
//This is not literally suitable.
foreach( string s in samplestring.Split(' '))
{
    yourstringbuilder.append(" and *");
    yourstringbuilder.append(s);
    yourstringbuilder.append("*");
}
```

?*/

EDIT: For your edited question  - just `result = result.remove(result.Length - " AND ".Length);` after your loop

Comment: I updated my question as i think i am doing what you say BUT i need to get rid of the ending AND...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly clean method.

```
public string BuildContainsClause(string filter)
{
    var keywords = filter
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(e => string.Format("\"*{0}*\"", e));

    return string.Format("CONTAINS(descr_en,'{0}')", string.Join(" AND ", keywords));
}
```

Usage:

```
var contains = BuildContainsClause("bottle 750 green");
// contains = "CONTAINS(descr_en,'\"*bottle*\" AND \"*750*\" AND \"*green*\"')"
```